# Loading pandas df to pytorch dataset loader results in "nan" training loss if df is shuffled

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pytorch

I am trying to train an autoencoder in pytorch.

When I am loading the data into a dataloader object like this, the autoencoder training works:

```
total_set = Dataset(df.iloc[:15000,1:], df.iloc[:15000,0])
```

However, when I load the data after shuffling or sampling from the dataset the autoencoder train loss is always nan.

```
df = df.sample(frac = 1).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df[(df != 0).all(1)].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
total_set = Dataset(df.iloc[:15000,1:], df.iloc[:15000,0])
```

I made sure I removed the 0 or nan values from the training set. Am I missing something here?

---

df.info() before and after shuffling:

before:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 513408 entries, 0 to 513407
Columns: 673 entries, 0 to 672
dtypes: float64(672), object(1)
memory usage: 2.6+ GB
None

after:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 513408 entries, 0 to 513407
Columns: 673 entries, 0 to 672
dtypes: float64(672), object(1)
memory usage: 2.6+ GB
None

Comment: Are you sure your df is correct after shuffling? You could check ```df.info()``` before passing it to ```Dataset()```

Comment: I checked with `df.head()` data looks fine. I just did `df.info()` too, it is same before and after the shuffle.

Comment: it looks like you are using the first column as a "label" and the other 672 as "input" - how many different "labels" do you have? is the `df` sorted according to the labels (prior to reshuffling)? What does your model predicts annd what is your loss?

Comment: I am using the other 672 for training an autoencoder. Loss is just the MSE reconstruction error. so I dont use the labels at all.